# WYSIWYG Editors and IFRAMEs

Tags: iframe, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

Re this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914510/wysiwyg-editor-without-iframe

Can someone explain why a lot of WYSIWYG editors use an IFRAME?

What are the good reasons for using an IFRAME?

Answer (score 0):

The most important reason is that it provides isolation from the page to the content, so it's possible to apply different stylesheets, use baseHref for images, edit a whole page including the headers...